# How to populate my django database with json that I scraped from a website

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I have scraped data from a website using their API on a Django application. The data is JSON (a Python dictionary when I retrieve it on my end). The data has many, many fields. I want to store them in a database, so that I can create endpoints that will allow for lookup and modifications (updates). I need to use their fields to create the structure of my database. Any help on this issue or on how to tackle it would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if my question is not concise enough, please let me know if there is anything I need to specify.

I have seen many, many people saying to just populate it, such as this example [How to populate a Django sqlite3 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884694/how-to-populate-a-django-sqlite3-database). The issue is, there are so many fields that I cannot go and actually create the django model fields myself. From what I have read, it seems like I may be able to use serializers.ModelSerializer, although that seems to just populate a pre-existing db with already defined model.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to answer without details, but I would consider doing this in two steps - first, convert your json data to a database schema, for example using a tool like sqlify: https://sqlify.io/convert/json/to/sqlite

Then, create a database from the generated schema file, and use inspectdb to generate your django models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

You'll probably need to tweak the generated schema and/or models, but this should go a long way towards automating the process.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this method a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a document database, like Elasticsearch or MongoDB.
Those are made for this kind of situation, look it up.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice. However, I am trying to use as few external dependencies with regards to software as I possibly can, and I am trying to stick with sqlite, as the project is not too large. But I will take note of this for future projects! Thanks!